# How to access bootstrap modal through url for SEO reasons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, url, seo, modal-dialog

I have a website made with Bootstrap and I use modal to show 3 links of content. The link for one of these modals, for exemple, is http://www.avss.com.br/#biodigestor. But if you put try to access this modal by putting this url on browser it won't show the modal as show the contact page http://www.avss.com.br/#contact.

My question is, there is how to make it happens?
Just because I need to configure this url on Google Webmasters Tools for SEO optimization.
Or, if there is another way to optimize its SEO, with the modal as it is, I will be thankful to know it!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Working Fiddle


I don't know much about SEO, but using jQuery and by checking the url entered, you can open a modal without clicking anywhere.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var host = window.location.host;
if(url.indexOf('http://' + host + '#contact'  ) != -1) { //instead of #contact give your url
  $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
}
```